# Tomcat redeploy not completely reloading webapp

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot

Using Apache Tomcat/8.5.24, running a Spring Boot application.

When we use the tomcat manager page and click "Reload" on our web-app, the app is not reloaded.  catalina.out says that the context has been reloaded, but Spring does not fire and our endpoints don't respond.  In order to get a real reload, we have to completely un-deploy the web app and re-deploy from scratch, which is less than ideal.

When I first deploy the app, I get the familiar

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.4.2.RELEASE)
```

Splash screen and all the associated controller bindings and bean creation logs.  However, when I click "reload", I get this

```
23-Jan-2018 15:13:17.235 INFO [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-10] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload Reloading Context with name [/myapp] has started
23-Jan-2018 15:13:17.237 INFO [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-10] org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext.doClose Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@283650df: startup date [Tue Jan 23 15:11:39 UTC 2018]; root of context hierarchy
23-Jan-2018 15:13:17.246 INFO [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-10] org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.stop Stopping beans in phase 2147483647
23-Jan-2018 15:13:17.247 INFO [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-10] org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.AnnotationMBeanExporter.destroy 
Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
System is shutting down
23-Jan-2018 15:13:17.428 INFO [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-10] org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.shutdown Shutting down ExecutorService 'getAsyncExecutor'
23-Jan-2018 15:13:17.542 INFO [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-10] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload Reloading Context with name [/myapp] is completed
```

And that's it.

We are using external jars, defined in a context.xml file as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Context path="/myapp" docBase="/myapp" reloadable="true">
    <Resources>
        <!-- Load the configuration files -->

        <!-- Location of external log4j2 configuration file -->
        <PreResources className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet"
            base="/mycompany/libs/config/"
            webAppMount="/WEB-INF/classes" />

        <!-- Location of the JARs -->
        <JarResources className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet"
            base="/mycompany/libs/application_core/"
            webAppMount="/WEB-INF/lib" />
        <JarResources className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet"
            base="/mycompany/libs/application_supplemental/"
            webAppMount="/WEB-INF/lib" />
        <JarResources className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet"
            base="/mycompany/libs/third_party/"
            webAppMount="/WEB-INF/lib" />
    </Resources>
</Context>
```

Before we moved to this structure, this wasn't an issue so I assume it has something to do with this configuration but I'm not extremely familiar with all things tomcat and am not sure where to even look.

Comment: Could you add your bootstrap and application properties?  What endpoints are you hitting before the reload? Do they start with /myapp ?

Comment: No bootstrap properties, application properties only give a Properties object for database credentials location, and the endpoints I'm hitting are the same before and after the reload.  They work fine before the reload, and don't respond afterwards.

Comment: Are you running an embedded tomcat or deploying to a different tomcat server?

Comment: Deploying to a different tomcat server

Comment: Are you sure that you aren't running tomcat inside of tomcat?

Comment: Can you share your pom.xml ?

Comment: Hey DaShaun, I'm pretty sure we're not running tomcat inside of tomcat; would tomcat deploy another version of tomcat inside of itself?  How would I even go about determining that?

Also, using gradle so no pom.xml but the dependencies haven't changed between the two versions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163821/discussion-between-dashaun-and-zeusalmighty).